# Magento date picker is not working when current date is disable

Tags: javascript, php, magento, datepicker

I am using the `magento date picker` in front end for select Delivery date of product. I want to **disable the previous dates, today and tomorrow**. For this I use:

```
disableFunc: function(date)  {                                  
    var now = new Date(Date.now() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    if(date.getFullYear()   <   now.getFullYear())  { return true; }
    if(date.getFullYear()   ==  now.getFullYear())  { if(date.getMonth()    <   now.getMonth()) { return true; } }
     if(date.getMonth()      ==  now.getMonth())     { if(date.getDate()     <   now.getDate())  { return true; } }
                },
```

The `dates are disabled`..OK. But `I can't select the enabled dates from date picker.`

If I use

```
var now = new Date();
```

instead of

```
var now = new Date(Date.now() + 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

The previous days only will disable. But the enabled dates can select from date picker.

Please help me..

Comment: I think, this question might help you. You've to change the logic according your needs.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648726/magento-datepicker-should-only-enable-two-days-after-today-today48hours/29673607#29673607

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.
In **js/calendar/calendar.js**
there is a variable `currentDateEl`. By default it is `null`.You just need to set 
`this.currentDateEl` to `current date.`

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var day = currentDate.getDate();
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
var dmy =  day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
this.currentDateEl = dmy;
```

and issue is solved now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to change your `calendar.js` file. Just add the `currentDateEl` in the `disableFunc`, like:

```
 disableFunc: function(date)  {
                var now = new Date();
                this.currentDateEl = now.getDate();
                if(date.getFullYear() < now.getFullYear()) { return true; }
                if(date.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() < now.getMonth()) { return true; }
                if(date.getMonth() == now.getMonth() && date.getDate() < now.getDate()) { return true; }
 }
```